# Users.messages list capping at number less than maxResults

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm currently using the Gmail API to list messages including a certain string. With maxResults set at any number (ex. 9000, 8000, 9999) the API caps the list at 511 when this number should be ~800 for my search.

For example, when searching for all emails including the string "A" and maxResults = 9999, it lists only 511 instances.

Is there a problem with the API listing more than 511 items? Has anyone had a similar problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are performing [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and your `maxResults` was set to a desired number more than what was fetched.

Try the [Try It](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it) in the Gmail API using your live data. If it returns with the same value as what was fetched by your code, then there's no problem neither with the API nor your code. It could be that you are missing something like using the [`nextPageToken`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269704/gmail-api-getting-all-gmail-inbox-messages-limits-to-500). Because I'm sure all your message was fetched and it's just not displayed in a single page.

[image]

See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269704/gmail-api-getting-all-gmail-inbox-messages-limits-to-500) for reference.